# What's the point of TSource in Linq statements?

Tags: c#, linq

A lot of statements (often seen in Linq) use TSource when it isn't required for either compilation or execution. Why would you specify TSource?

Example:

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>(5) { 0, 1, 2, 0, 3 };

 int x = list.Where<int>(i => i == 0).FirstOrDefault<int>();
 int y = list.Where(i => i == 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do the statements differ?

Comment: what examples are you looking at that "use TSource when it isn't required" ? Most code that I see *does not* do this; nor does the LINQ comprehension specification ( `where x.IsAlive` becomes `.Where(x => x.IsAlive)` ).

Comment: Some people don't mind writing redundant code, such as explicitly specifying a type where `var` would do, or using `FirstOrDefault` right after a `Where(predicate)`, when `FirstOrDefault(predicate)` would do. Who knows what such people are thinking ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both of your LINQ statements the `TSource` type is required.

It is just explicitly provided in the first statement and implicitly **inferred** in the second.

You would specify `TSource` in circumstances where the compiler cannot infer the type - often when the lambda is nested and very complicated.

Also, if you wanted the operation to be performed using a supertype of type used in the lamdba. For example, you might specify the `Fruit` type rather than let it infer `Apple` if `Apple` inherits from `Fruit`.

Finally, you may choose to specify (or not) the `TSource` just to make your code more readable - either by explicitly including the type or by removing redundant type repetition.

Comment: But why would you specify TSource or not?

Answer (score 1):

Because sometimes (and I mean sometimes) if we do not define `TSource` then it cannot detect its type from its usage i.e. its lambda expression.

Sometimes haven't we got this error if we do not provide `TSource`.

In your case it is OK if we do not provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes it is totally redundant and does not serve any real purpose. I suspect that some code tools like refactoring engines add generic parameters even if not necessary.

Resharper flags those as redundant and I usually remove them. They don't add valuable information and the don't (usually) document something important.

Comment: It's not that the parameter itself is redundant, just that the value can be implied (explicitly declaring it is redundant).  There's a difference there that I don't think you make clear.